# Compare rows of two dataframes to find the matching column count of 1's

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes with same schema, i need to compare the rows of dataframes and keep a count of rows with at-least one column with value 1 in both the dataframes

Right now i am making a list of the rows and then comparing the 2 lists to find even if one value is equal in both the list and equal to 1

```
rowOgList = []
for row in cat_og_df.rdd.toLocalIterator():
    rowOgDict = {}
    for cat in categories:
        rowOgDict[cat] = row[cat]
    rowOgList.append(rowOgDict)

#print(rowOgList[0])

rowPredList = []
for row in prob_df.rdd.toLocalIterator():
    rowPredDict = {}
    for cat in categories:
        rowPredDict[cat] = row[cat]
    rowPredList.append(rowPredDict)
```

But here the function rdd.tolocalIterator gives me a heap space error when i try it on a huge dataset.
for example:
this is the 1st dataframe

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|column3|column4|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|      0|      0|      0|      0|
|      0|      0|      0|      0|
|      0|      0|      0|      0|
|      1|      0|      0|      0|
|      0|      0|      0|      0|
|      0|      0|      0|      0|
|      0|      1|      0|      0|
|      0|      0|      0|      0|
|      0|      0|      1|      0|
|      0|      0|      0|      0|
|      0|      0|      0|      1|
|      0|      0|      0|      0|
|      0|      0|      0|      0|
|      0|      0|      0|      0|
|      0|      0|      0|      0|
|      0|      0|      0|      0|
|      1|      0|      0|      0|
|      0|      0|      1|      0|
|      0|      0|      0|      0|
|      0|      0|      0|      0|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

this is the 2nd dataframe

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|column3|column4|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|      1|      0|      1|      0|
|      1|      0|      1|      0|
|      0|      0|      1|      1|
|      0|      0|      1|      1|
|      1|      0|      1|      0|
|      1|      0|      1|      0|
|      1|      0|      1|      0|
|      1|      0|      1|      0|
|      0|      0|      1|      1|
|      1|      0|      1|      0|
|      0|      0|      1|      1|
|      1|      0|      1|      0|
|      1|      0|      1|      0|
|      1|      0|      1|      0|
|      1|      0|      1|      0|
|      1|      0|      1|      0|
|      1|      0|      1|      0|
|      1|      0|      1|      0|
|      1|      0|      1|      0|
|      1|      0|      1|      0|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

here rows 9,11,17,18 have at least one column with same value and that value as 1
so here the count = 4

Can this be done in any optimized way, Thanks.

Comment: One way to do it if your data is sparse enough, you can `rdd.map` through each row and record the index corresponding to a cell with 1. After doing this with both dataframes, you can then compare which indices are present in both dataframes in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i am not quite getting what you are suggesting, can you help me with some example

Comment: You can't simply rely on the order of rows to join the two dataframes. Do you have a primary key?

Comment: No i dont have a primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note :  As mentioned by pault, this will work better if you have unique row indices that connect both dataframes. Otherwise, the row orders may not be guaranteed in some Spark operations.

**(1)** Setup the environment and some sample data.

```
import numpy as np

from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 0, 1),
    (1, 0, 0),
    (0, 0, 1)
], ["column1", "column2", "column3"])

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 0, 0),
    (1, 0, 1),
    (0, 0, 1)
], ["column1", "column2", "column3"])
```

**(2)** Collect all columns into a Spark vector.

```
assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=["column1", "column2", "column3"],
    outputCol="merged_col")

df1_merged = assembler.transform(df1)
df2_merged = assembler.transform(df2)
```

```
df1_merged.show()

+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
|column1|column2|column3|   merged_col|
+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
|      0|      0|      1|[0.0,0.0,1.0]|
|      1|      0|      0|[1.0,0.0,0.0]|
|      0|      0|      1|[0.0,0.0,1.0]|
+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

**(3)** Get the row and column index of non-zero elements. Using numpy.nonzero() on RDD of Spark Vector.

```
def get_nonzero_index(args):
    (row, index) = args
    np_arr = np.array(row.merged_col)
    return (index, np_arr.nonzero()[0].tolist())

df1_ind_rdd = df1_merged.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(get_nonzero_index)
df2_ind_rdd = df2_merged.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(get_nonzero_index)
```

```
df1_ind_rdd.collect()
[(0, [2]), (1, [0]), (2, [2])]

df2_ind_rdd.collect()
[(0, []), (1, [0, 2]), (2, [2])]
```

**(4)** You can then do your comparison on these 2 Python lists easily.

Note that this method will not be efficient (due to `collect`) if the number of rows you have is very large. In that case, you will want to do all processing in Spark by doing a join on the 2 dataframes.

**(5)** To do the matching purely in Spark, you can try the methods below that rely on a join on row index.

```
df1_index = spark.createDataFrame(df1_ind_rdd, ["row_index_1", "column_index_1"])
df2_index = spark.createDataFrame(df2_ind_rdd, ["row_index_2", "column_index_2"])

df_joined = df1_index.join(df2_index, df1_index.row_index_1 == df2_index.row_index_2)
```

Then expand the list so that we get an element on each row.

```
df_exploded = df_joined.withColumn("column_index_exp_1", F.explode(df_joined.column_index_1))\
                            .withColumn("column_index_exp_2", F.explode(df_joined.column_index_2))
```

Check for match between the two columns and finally convert into integer for summing.

```
df_match_bool = df_exploded.withColumn("match_bool", df_exploded.column_index_exp_1 == df_exploded.column_index_exp_2)

df_match_int = df_match_bool.withColumn("match_integer", df_match_bool.match_bool.cast("long"))
```

```
df_match_bool.show()
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+------------------+----------+
|row_index_1|column_index_1|row_index_2|column_index_2|column_index_exp_1|column_index_exp_2|match_bool|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+------------------+----------+
|          1|           [0]|          1|        [0, 2]|                 0|                 0|      true|
|          1|           [0]|          1|        [0, 2]|                 0|                 2|     false|
|          2|           [2]|          2|           [2]|                 2|                 2|      true|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+------------------+----------+
```

```
df_match_int.groupBy().sum("match_integer").collect()[0][0]
2
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wrote some code according to your suggestion and its working. Will try your code as and when i get time. Will accept this as the answer once i try it.

Comment: I tried your solution. It works but with slight modifications that i had to do on my side. Thanks, accepting it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> For **Spark 2.4** and for smallish number of columns and with a degree of performance
>   penalty as whole array processed, but in parallel. Num cols is 5, as an
>   example. Dynamic schema columns definitions. Tidy up of declaration
>   required here This approach is for any value, need to restrict to 1's
>   only. Filter added. Certain approaches do not appear to work in lower versions of Spark. Tested this.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col, split, arrays_zip, expr, lit
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import * 
from pyspark.sql import Row

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
(1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
(1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)      ], ["column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", "column5"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
(0, 1, 1, 1, 1),
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)      ], ["column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", "column5"])

schema1 = StructType(df1.schema.fields[:] + [StructField("index1", LongType(), True)])
schema2 = StructType(df2.schema.fields[:] + [StructField("index2", LongType(), True)])
allCols = [x for x in df1.columns] # at this stage common to both DFs - df1 & df2

rdd1 = df1.rdd.zipWithIndex()
rdd2 = df2.rdd.zipWithIndex()
# All narrow transformations, so zipWithIndex should be fine  

rddA = rdd1.map(lambda row: tuple(row[0].asDict()[c] for c in schema1.fieldNames()[:-1]) + (row[1],))
dfA = spark.createDataFrame(rddA, schema1)
rddB = rdd2.map(lambda row: tuple(row[0].asDict()[c] for c in schema2.fieldNames()[:-1]) + (row[1],))
dfB = spark.createDataFrame(rddB, schema2)

dfA = dfA.withColumn("merged_col1", F.concat_ws(',', *allCols))
dfB = dfB.withColumn("merged_col2", F.concat_ws(',', *allCols))
dfC = dfA.join(dfB, dfA.index1 == dfB.index2).select("index1", "merged_col1", "merged_col2") 
dfD = dfC.select(col("index1"), split(col("merged_col1"), ",\s*").cast("array<int>").alias("ev1"), split(col("merged_col2"), ",\s*").cast("array<int>").alias("ev2"))
dfE = dfD.withColumn("matches", expr("filter(sequence(0,size(ev1)-1), (i -> ev1[i] == 1 and ev1[i] == ev2[i]))"))    
dfF = dfE.withColumn("matchesSize", F.size(F.col("matches")))
dfF.filter(F.col("matchesSize") > 0).show()
```

returns in this simulated case:

```
+------+---------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
|index1|            ev1|            ev2|matches|matchesSize|
+------+---------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
|     0|[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]|[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]| [0, 1]|          2|
|     1|[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]|[0, 1, 1, 1, 1]|    [4]|          1|
+------+---------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
```

You need to manipulate the data further in terms of count, etc. and what you want to display. There is enough data to do that.

> I am not a pyspark expert by any means, but interesting question. And
>   this does not have explode etc. Simpler than other answer I feel with
>   good parallelism possible, can optimize further, but we leave that to
>   you in terms of partitioning. Down-side is all values processed when
>   in fact when should stop on 1st find. Would need a UDF for that I
>   suspect.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i am getting an error on the following line:    dfE = dfD.withColumn("matches", expr("filter(sequence(0,size(ev1)-1), (i -> ev1[i] == 1 and ev1[i] == ev2[i]))"))  this is the error:     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
no viable alternative at input '(i ->'(line 1, pos 36)
== SQL ==
filter(sequence(0,size(ev1)-1), (i -> ev1[i] == 1 and ev1[i] == ev2[i]))

Comment: Just FYI i am using spark version 2.2.0

Comment: I will check later. should work on lower version, will get back. Did u run exact script?

Comment: Indeed < 2.4 has some issues, oh well, you know this when you get to use a better release.

Comment: I looked into 2.2 but not could not get it to work with UDFs. Things are somewhat easier with 2.4.3.

Comment: Well i found a work around using udf, will try it out soon. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, I can do it in 2.4, but for some reason I found an issue in 2.2 that cols were not found. Please share the UDF.

Comment: At the very least this approach avoids explosion and is there better in performance. Partial credit is always a good thing.

Comment: Rest things remain the same                                                                  
`matcher = udf(lambda a,b:[i for i,item in enumerate(a) if item==1 and item==b[i]], ArrayType(StringType()))                                                                 
...
dfE = dfD.withColumn("matches", matcher('ev1','ev2'))`      Also instead of col("index1") use df.index1

Comment: beaut, in 2.2 I will try tonight.

Comment: Even in 2.2 in Databricks I cannot this to run... will have to leave

Comment: I think this is the issue in 2.2 rddA = rdd1.map(lambda row: tuple(row[0].asDict()[c] for c in schema1.fieldNames()[:-1]) + (row[1],))

Comment: Use schema1.names()[:-1] theres no fieldNames in 2.2, sorry i forgot to mention that

Comment: joh, I will try later but I am happy with the 2.4.3 solution